# Lack of some useful functions of mysql_* in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'd like to have a MySQL query or table object, say one that takes PDO object as input and doing all the necessary stuff with the table.

I was thinking that this object could implement some array interfaces, like `Countable`, `ArrayAccess`, `Iterator` so I could easily `foreach` the rows like it was a regular array.

In deprecated `mysql_*` functions there was (still is, yet) very useful function [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php), which helped to move row-by-row, so I could implement all `Iterator` methods. I could run one query at the beginning and keep the rows in some resource private field and serve if I needed to.

The other functions (mostly informational, like [`mysql_list_tables()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php) and similar) I can cover by sending proper query to the db and fetch the result, but how could I move to specific row?

I thought that the last parameter of the [`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method is the cursor position, but when I call

```
$p = $database->query('SELECT * FROM tobjects');
$row = $p->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_CURSOR,$i);
```

it's always resulting the same row for any value of `$i`.

**EDIT**

Actually, it's not the same row, but the first row at the first call to `fetch()`, second row for second etc., like there was no cursor information. As suggested in answers I did this

```
$p = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM tobjects',
                    array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
$p->execute();
$row = $p->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, $i);
```

but this works the same.

Comment: I ran into trouble with this as well. (Apparently, MySQL [doesn't support scrollable cursors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#105277).) The best solution I found (for small record sets) is to use `fetchAll` to fetch the record set into an array. Then traverse the array instead of the query.

Comment: @showdev I thought about it, but it's then loading to memory lots of useless data.

Comment: That's true, especially for large sets of data.

Comment: Why would you select useless data anyway?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't know now. But I don't think it's necessary to get all the data when (at the moment) I want one row. However, I hoped it was.

Comment: Well, select one row if you need one row. What's the problem?

Comment: @YourCommonSense The problem is to possibility of sending multiple queries `...WHERE id = $i` but I think I should handle this with one query

Comment: Go on, handle it with one query. Look, no PHP programmer ever have a problem like yours. There is something wrong with your design may be? Can you tell me whatever use case you don't know how to handle?

Comment: There is something (an object) that takes rows from the db table (my object). It takes all of them. There is another object that needs only one specific record from the table and uses the same my object. There is a third object that does not want any rows to retrieve but deletes them all. Sometimes I need to retrieve one row, sometimes all, sometimes none. I don't want to think what query should I prepare, what parameters bind and not forget to execute. That's why I thought I could use such an interface to the db table. I know I can prepare query, I can do it but I hoped I didn't have to.

Comment: That's SQL. Means all database interactions are done by means of SQL query. If you don't like SQL but want to map a table even of millions of records and traverse it one by one line - may be MySQL and PHP aren't too good a choice for your demands. But... sql aren't that bad. I can assure you. At least give it a try.

Comment: OK, thank you and all others for help. As concerning to the question, it is not possible to do this with the PDO. As of other remarks/suggestions of @YourCommonSense I see I need to rethink this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `PDO::ATTR_CURSOR` wrong. What you need to do is request a scrollable cursor first by using `PDO::prepare`, and then you can move to any record you want in the result set:

```
$s = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM tobjects',
                        [PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL]);
$s->execute();
$row = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, $i);
```

Comment: There is a syntax error because of `[`, but I changed as Philip said `array(...)` and it's returning the first row only.

Comment: As far as I can tell, MySQL [does not support scrollable cursors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#105277). If anyone has information to the contrary, please let us know!

Comment: @Voitcus: The `[...]` is legal array syntax for PHP >= 5.4.0. However, it seems MySql does not support scrollable cursors as @showdev says. I 'm afraid there is nothing you can do about that except implement this feature another way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any of these functions useful for whatever real life scenario.

mysql_list_tables() indeed can be substituted with WAY more informative and flexible query to INFORMATION SCHEMA

Why bother with implementing ArrayAccess if you can have a regular array already? 
There are only 2 scenarios:

- either you need relatively small amount of data, fits for the web page. Just select it all at once.

  ```
  $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
  ```

  And you can traverse the resulting array whatever way you like.
- or you need to traverse long table in some sort of console service script. You don't need traverse it back and forth then. Just select and loop over.

Comment: I wanted to traverse my object, that I create by giving the `$database` with is PDO object and table name. All the things like `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` could be handled by proper queries, but I wouldn't need to prepare `DELETE` query, then run this, but I can call the method `deleteRow($id)` and that's all, I wouldn't need to care about if I should `INSERT`or `UPDATE` (the schema is such that I'm not sure if I can use `UPDATE IF NOT EXISTS INSERT`) and so on. (I know about taking all data from schema and that's ok.)

Comment: I still can't get your problem. Dozens of ORMs happily use their deleteRow() methods already. Why can't you create some of your own or use whatever ready made one?

Comment: I'm new to it, wanted to learn something and not rely on others' libraries that I don't understand.

Comment: The main thing you need to learn on PHP: it is not a solid application that is running for hours. It's rather number of small scripts, each runs for a fraction of second to serve particular page. You can always tell which data you will need on this particular page and select it. Do not select anything else as it will die a moment after. So - always just select the data you need at the moment and nothing else. That's all